# Вместо изменения transform - объект начинает дергаться Unity

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-android

Есть скрипт, отвечающий за открытие двери (изменение transform).

```
void Update()
    {
            if (open)
            {
                if (AudioS == false)
                {
                    gameObject.GetComponent<AudioSource>().PlayOneShot(OpenAudio);
                    AudioS = true;
                }
                door.transform.eulerAngles = Vector3.Slerp(transform.eulerAngles, openRot, Time.deltaTime * smooth);
            }
            else
            {
                if (AudioS == true)
                {
                    gameObject.GetComponent<AudioSource>().PlayOneShot(CloseAudio);
                    AudioS = false;
                }
                door.transform.eulerAngles = Vector3.Slerp(transform.eulerAngles, defaultRot, Time.deltaTime * smooth);

            }
    }
```

Дело в том, что когда я задаю GameObject `door` статично (через инспектор например) - все работает отлично. Дверь свободно открывается. Но когда я пытаюсь задать `door` в процессе выполнения кода (через триггеры) прим:

```
public void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        Debug.Log(other.gameObject.name);
        if (this.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            Opendoor2.door = other.gameObject;
        }
    }
```

То открытие двери не осуществляется. Оно реагирует на Открытие/Закрытие: воспроизводит звук и т.д, но сама дверь не открывается. Единственное, что она начинает дергаться вокруг оси (неполное открытие/закрытие) в диапазоне небольшого угла. Как с этим бороться? И как это исправить? Буду рад любой помощи, заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте += вместо = :

```
door.transform.eulerAngles += Vector3.Slerp(transform.eulerAngles, defaultRot, 
Time.deltaTime * smooth);
```

и

```
door.transform.eulerAngles += Vector3.Slerp(transform.eulerAngles, openRot, 
Time.deltaTime * smooth);
```

А также я не вижу смысла писать if(AudioS == false) если можно if(!AudioS), но это уже как вам удобно.